# Disable "Unhandled Exception" Error?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm planning on releasing a beta version of my product fairly soon and I think the whole deal with the "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application" looks really unprofessional on a commercial product. Instead of having this, I would rather the program just stop responding completely rather than display this "advanced looking" error.

Comment: winforms, wpf, asp.net, which land are you from?

Comment: I would really have to say that the best approach here is to get better at proper exception handling so this never happens. Please do **NOT** just wrap everything in `catch (Exception)` - that's terrible. Have a read of Eric Lippert's discussion on exceptions - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: @MathewJibin WinForms

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you, I will check it out.

Answer (score -3):

Just wrap the startup in try/catch block.

```
try
{
   Application.Run(new Form1());
}
catch (Exception)
{
   // leave it blank (highly not recommended!! See comments) or do whatever else you want here,
}
```

Comment: Oh please do not do this. Like ever.

Comment: Yes, this is terrible. Don't do it.

Comment: I fully agree, just answering question. My understanding of SO is no opinions.

Comment: People will often downvote answers that are dangerous or bad practice - as is, this fits that description. You may want to consider some edits to clarify that.

Comment: @Krease Did that. Thank you

Comment: @MotKohn - No, that's not right. SO is full of opinion. What's not on-topic are questions that encourage primarily opinion-based answers, rather than answers based on facts, references, or specific expertise.